# Find the point of intersection of the three planes.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Find the point of intersection of the three planes

> \begin{align}
> x-2y+z=4\\
> 3x+y-2z=1\\
> 4x-y+3z=6
> \end{align}

I'll show how far I got to and then state the issue I have.

Each of the planes above has a normal vector. They are as follows respectively:

\begin{align}
N_1=[1,-2,1]\\
N_2=[3,1,-2]\\
N_3=[4,-1,3]
\end{align}

Next, I want to find a vector $V=[a,b,c]$ such that the inner product $V \cdot N_i = 0$, for $i=1,2,3$. That is we need to solve the following system of equations:

\begin{align}
a-2b+c=0 \tag1\\
3a+b-2c=0 \tag2\\
4a-b+3c=0 \tag3
\end{align}

If we multiply equations $(2)$ and $(3)$ by $2$ and then sum equations $(1)+(2)$ and $(2)+(3)$, we get the following:

\begin{align}
7a-3c=0\\
14a+2c=0
\end{align}

Then setting the above equations equal to each other and solving for $a$ and $c$, we get a non-unique solution $a=5$ and $c=-7$. Here's the issue I'm getting. If we plug in these values of $a$ and $c$ into equations $(1)$ and $(3)$, we get $b=-1$, but when we instead use  equation $(2)$, we get $b=-29$.

What is going on?

Comment: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=duFRYId7kNU

Comment: At the step where you have 2 equations in a and c, you should not "set them equal." Instead solve one for a and plug into the other, then you just get a=c=0. Then back to the other equations get also b=0.

Comment: Your equations in a,b,c show they are all zero, which means that only the zero vector is orthogonal to each of the normal vectors of your plane. If you just go directly with solving the given three equations in three unknowns x,y,z you do get a unique solution. I'll let you try again to find it. Just work with th original equations in the usual way.

Comment: @User3910 great video thanks! I didn't know  $N_1 \cdot N_2 \times N_3 \neq 0$ would tell me if I get a unique point of intersection. Thanks again!

Comment: @coffeemath interesting, then yes I'll just solve for x,y,z (I won't use Row Echelon or any other matrix technique because technically I didn't get to that part of my textbook yet).